# How to programmatically create a TermGroup which is accessible and usable through all SiteCollection

Tags: 2013, development, term-store, term, term-set

I want to know how to programmatically create a TermGroup which is accessible and usable through all SiteCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As state [here](http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html). I used it and it worked for me!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   

        var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";

        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){

                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", execOperation);

                });
            }
        );

    });

    function execOperation(){

        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

        //Term Store under which to create the group.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");      

        //New Group with name and new GUID
        var newGroup = termStore.createGroup("New Group Name","b300304a-1693-4629-a1c0-dff7bda644ff");

        context.load(newGroup);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        console.log(newGroup.get_name());

        },function(sender,args){

        console.log(args.get_message());

        });

    }
```

For c# see [here](http://www.prodataman.com/Blog/Post/94/C--Console-App---Create-a-SharePoint-2013-Managed-Metadata-Term-Set). I did not test it!

Comment: Thanks, but you always have to reference a SiteCollection. Is there a way to leave this off? When you go to the Central Administration an then the to the TermStore, there is no need to reference a SiteCollection. And this is my question: how to do this in code (C#) without referencing a SiteCollection?

Comment: Has noone did this before? Or am i wrong with my requirements?